# How to prove $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}<\log(n)<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k}$

Tags: integration, logarithms, riemann-sum

> How to prove $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}<\log(n)<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k}$

It is clear if i consider the area under $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x})$ from $1$ to $n$ end divide the interval $[1,n]$ into subintervals of length $1$, since $1/x$ is strictly decreasing LHS of the inequality takes the minimum value and RHS the maximum, so $\log(n)$ is always between them.

> But I want to show that with Riemann-Sum, is this  possible ?

I tried:

$(f(x):=\dfrac{1}{x})$

$$\log(n)={\displaystyle\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{dx}{x}}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{n-1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}f\left(1+\dfrac{i(n-1)}{k}\right)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\dfrac{n-1}{k+i(n-1)}$$

Now I'm stuck, how can i compare this with the sums above

Comment: Isn't what you did (considering left sums and right sums) exactly using Riemann sums?

Comment: @TMM but i didn't show it yet. I only wrote log(n) as riemann sum

Comment: So are you saying that you know that the LHS and the RHS are the respective Riemann sums, but that you are stuck proving *algebraically* that they are less and greater than $\log n$?

Comment: @TMM YES i mean exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're trying to get at the Riemann sums resulting from subdividing each interval $[k, k+1]$ into $m$ equal-length pieces? This gives
$$
\frac{1}{k+1}
  = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}
  < \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{k + \frac{i}{m}}
  < \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k},
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}
  < \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{k + \frac{i}{m}}
  = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m(n-1)} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{j}{m}}
  < \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k},
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m(n-1)} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{j}{m}}
  = \sum_{j=1}^{m(n-1)} f(x_{j})\, \Delta x_{j}
  \approx \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}\, dx.
$$

Comment: I think this is the answer. Can't find any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>1$  $$\log(n)=\int_1^n\frac{1}{x}dx$$ thus $$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}\leq\log(n)\leq\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: I didn't mean that. Why is $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\le\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\dfrac{n-1}{k+i(n-1)}$

Comment: @O.B.D.A., your question's title asks **precisely** what the above answer is trying to answer. How come you "did not mean that"? Even reading what you wrote that is only one try...

Comment: @DonAntonio do you see my comment above yours, can you prove that ?

Comment: The right hand limit seems to yield a divergent series, @O.B.D.A.: a special case of he armonic series since $\;n\;$ is constant there...

Comment: @DonAntonio RHS is not divergent, it must converge to log (n) if k tends to infinity (and if i wrote the riemann sum correctly). But do you understand my question now. I want to show the inequality by only considering these sums.

Comment: It doesn't look like a series to me. It looks like a sequence, but not of partial sums, as the generic term depends on the upper bound. It must be convergent though.

Comment: The sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\ln(n)$ converges to the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: And you do not need to subdivide the interval $[k,k+1)$, considering $\frac1{k+1}\le\frac1x\le \frac1k$ for all $x\in[k,k+1)$ and using that for the upper and lower Riemann sums over $[1,n]$ is quite sufficient for the question and leads to the inequalities used in this answer. $f(x)=\frac1x$ is continuous on $[1,\infty)$, so one does not need to prove integrability.