# inequality with ln(n)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

I've seen proofs of $$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \leq \ln n$$ but I have also seen the inequality $$ \ln n \leq \displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i}$$ which I have trouble proving ( if it is provable).

Comment: Compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702857/how-to-prove-sum-limits-k-2n-dfrac1k-logn-sum-limits-k-1n-1.

Comment: [The Euler Maclaurin Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula) provides a rigorous way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you probably saw this, not the one you said

$$\ln n\leq \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i-1}$$

Your inequality doesn't hold for $n\geq3$. Check with your calculator that

$$\ln 3 > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$$

For your reference to show $\ln n\leq \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i-1}$:

$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+[x]}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{[x]}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}\leq \ln n\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i}\leq \ln n\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}=\leq \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i-1}$$